# How to create a password protected zipfile with python?

Tags: python, zip

Since python2.6, it's now easier to extract data from a password protected zip. But how to create a password protected zipfile in pure python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked for this in the past and been unsuccessful.  (I'd love to see a solution get posted!)

One option is a commercial package from chilkatsoft that will do this, but at $150.  Makes sense if you are doing a commercial app, but tough to swallow otherwise.

I wound up calling out to the system for my solution, a while ago.  Unfortunately, this locks it to a platform.